# Django Rest Framework, HyperlinkedModelSerializers, ModelViewSets, and writable GenericForeignKeys: how?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got a model `FinancialTransaction` which has the typical `content_type`, `object_id`, and `content_object` fields to set up generic relations to any of my other models.

I've figured out how to serialize this relation for reading:

```
class FinancialTransactionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    content_object = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_content_obj_url')

    def get_content_obj_url(self, obj):
        obj = obj.content_object

        view_name = obj._meta.object_name.lower() + "-detail"
        s = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(source=obj, view_name=view_name)
        s.initialize(self, None)
        return s.field_to_native(obj, None)

    class Meta:
        model = FinancialTransaction
        fields = ('id', 'value', 'date', 'memo', 'banking_account', 'content_object')
```

The ViewSet:

```
class FinancialTransactionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = FinancialTransaction
    serializer_class = FinancialTransactionSerializer
```

This creates a hyperlink to the related object for the serialized representation when I do a GET on the view.

However, I'm kind of stuck on how to make it so that I can POST a new FinancialTransaction with an already existing related object.

Ideally, it would work just like a normal ForeignKey where I can POST something like:

```
{"value": "200.00",
 "date": "2014-10-10",
 "memo": "repairs",
 "banking_account": "http://domain.com/api/banking_account/134/",
 "content_object": "http://domain.com/api/property/432/"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question...

I overrode `restore_fields` in my own serializer like this:

```
class FinancialTransactionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    content_object = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_content_obj_url')

    def get_content_obj_url(self, obj):
        obj = obj.content_object

        view_name = get_view_name(obj)
        s = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(source=obj, view_name=view_name)
        s.initialize(self, None)
        return s.field_to_native(obj, None)

    def restore_fields(self, data, files):
        content_object = None

        if 'content_object' in data:
            request = self.context.get('request')  
            content_object = get_object_from_url(request.DATA['content_object'])

        attrs = super(FinancialTransactionSerializer, self).restore_fields(data, files)
        if content_object:
            attrs['content_object'] = content_object
        return attrs

    class Meta:
        model = FinancialTransaction
        fields = ('id', 'value', 'date', 'memo', 'banking_account', 'content_object')

def get_model_from_url(url: str):
    return resolve(urlparse(url).path).func.cls.model

def get_object_from_url(url: str):
    model = get_model_from_url(url)
    pk = resolve(urlparse(url).path).kwargs.get('pk')
    if not pk:
        return None
    return model.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

This setup serializes objects so that the `content_object` field contains a hyperlink to the related object, and when POST'ing to a view using this serializer, and the data includes the `content_object` key, we get the related object and pass it on.

The attrs returned from `restore_fields` is used in the `restore_object` method, and since we looked up the content object and put it in attrs, `restore_object` sets the `content_object` attribute on the FinancialTransaction object to the retrieved object and then Django takes care of the rest.

So far the only downside I can see is that this doesn't add the `content_object` field to the browsable API...but I'm not sure how that'd work anyway since related objects are  usually provided in a select, and I don't think we'd want a select populated with every single object in our database.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more in this DOC: [Marking extra actions for routing](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#marking-extra-actions-for-routing), if you need specified routing for your `POST` request, see their code sample:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets
# See these imports
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route, list_route
from rest_framework.response import Response
from myapp.serializers import UserSerializer, PasswordSerializer

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides the standard actions
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    # just place your logical def with the existing decorator, like so:
    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = PasswordSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user.set_password(serializer.data['password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'status': 'password set'})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, as it got me digging into the docs more.  It felt like this functionality belonged in the serializer more than in the view, so I [figured out how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26854505/23972).